# Remove values with some similarities in a map using kotlin streams

Tags: kotlin

I have a `map<String, MyObject>` where the values in the map could have same values for some variables (e.g., `name` parameter in my example). I would appreciate any solution using streams to remove entries with same `name` parameter on the value and keep only one of them with minimum `id`.

```
data class MyObject(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

For instance my map could be:

```
[
"first" to MyObject(1, "Alice"),
"second" to MyObject(2, "Bob"),
"third" to MyObject(3, "Alice")
]
```

and the expected output is:

```
[
"first" to MyObject(1, "Alice"),
"second" to MyObject(2, "Bob")
]
```

where the entry with key `third` is removed because the value has the same `name` as the first entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to identify all of the duplicate candidates. We can do that with [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html), which works on any iterable (and `Map` is iterable with iteratee type `Entry<K, V>`).

```
myMap.entries
     .groupBy({ entry => entry.value.name })
```

This produces a value of type `Map<String, List<Entry<String, MyObject>>>`.

Now, for each value in the map, we want to choose the element in the list with the smallest ID. We can select the minimum element by some condition using [`minBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by.html) and can do that to each element of a map with [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html).

```
myMap.entries
     .groupBy({ entry => entry.value.name })
     .mapValues({ entry => entry.value.minBy({ it.value.id })!! })
```

(Note: `groupBy` always produces nonempty lists, since it's partitioning a set, so we can confidently `!!` assert that a minimum exists)

Finally, this returns a `Map<String, Entry<String, MyObject>>`, and you probably want to eliminate the excess `Map` layer.

```
myMap.entries
     .groupBy({ entry -> entry.value.name })
     .mapValues({ entry -> entry.value.minBy({ it.value.id })!! })
     .values
     .associate({ it.key to it.value })
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBasMwDL3nK9ScbOgC225hK7S3HUoPg93dxMm0OnawlYEp/fZMTlLCBtNJenpPT9LFkUE7jrUiBZVRIcAxns5fuiLxrQxgXcKbpS2kwqpOl/BOHm0rs6wZLHQKrVC@DSXsvVfxZe7uJFwzmERdPKoeXpnZnxqRN@gD5UBu9XncQr43WOlcchZ05Wz9m/HE@MGdpz59ov/Tfl4HyMXV6zAYSrbJnkGOQlteToelar0b@kMUV0h4hIfdnBSsH3SRjoWbXMi8/UeCw3/0Du00C2kBsGb1ZrOOmOC7OT/aVahIz5KLjumiu3gW9fxJMlbMt8jsNo4/)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning this doesn't specifically use Java streams, which the OP requested (though I imagine that's not a true practical constraint).

Comment: @Tenfour04 True, though I'm guessing OP is just confused. They talk about "Kotlin streams", which is not a thing that exists (`kotlin.streams` is a compatibility package for working with Java streams), and the only mention of Java streams is in the tags. I'm guessing OP is coming from Java, where you have to make a conscious effort to move from a "collection" mindset to a "stream" mindset, and hasn't yet figured out that there's no such mental shift in Kotlin.

Comment: Can the `.entries` be omitted, since the map itself is iterable?

Comment: @k314159 Are maps iterable in Kotlin? I would have assumed they were but was surprised to find [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) seems to not indicate that they are not.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm sorry for the confusion regarding streams and java-stream! I removed the tag from the question. I only meant using streams instead of going through entries and "manually" taking additional variables to solve the problem.

Comment: @HamidGhasemi That's what I figured. Totally understandable. But Java is really the only language that makes a huge fanfare out of that and gives it a name. In languages like Kotlin, Scala, Ruby, etc. that have better built-in collection libraries, streaming operations are common enough that we don't really give them a separate name, per se.

Comment: You said it yourself in your answer, that "Map is iterable"! To be precise, they don't implement the Iterable interface, but they do have an iterator() function which means they can be iterated.

Comment: @k314159 Maps can be iterated in a `for` loop because of the `iterator()` function, but the `iterator()` function alone doesn't make it eligible for all the `Iterable` extension functions. You cannot omit `entries` here.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this using pure Kotlin, here is one relying on the fact that hash-maps do not allow duplicates. I am sure there are better solutions out there:

```
values.toList()
     // If you care about the smaller id number value
     // then sort by descending so they replace larger values.
    .sortedByDescending { it.second.id }
     // Will replace duplicates by hashing technique
    .associateBy { it.second.name }
     // Back to the same data structure
    .map { it.value.first to it.value.second }.toMap()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBasMwDIbvfgqRUwwhsO0WtkHDLoWWHvYEru102lw72OoglDx7psS0oTP4IPnTr9//TyCHfpqMIgXaqZRgPxyO31ZT@ascoGlg66mCufDqbBv4pIj@JIWYW3wvNsEbnFV/6EoBfIoOY6ICKKxaTxUUG4faFrLKULI6ePNIPTPVhuOdoS@M/5CXVUiwh@7ieTX6UsVTamAToxpes8N3CVeWyQ4XPYCawg4TlfJWpxDJmnb4sElbb3gMroBUZ3c1GhhvKGcTNCqy7fDAzKmsFOeQX5e99RLF/IF7J0/ByFb2ql@dOEtl0/TsnJyXYpymPw)

Comment: Worth noting that this answer does assume that the map will be iterated in increasing order of ID. If not, then the `reversed` call will have to be a `sortBy` instead, to get the right order.

Comment: Good shout, updated to reflect that, thanks!

Comment: @U-ways I went for the other solution as it contained a detailed explanation and gave me more flexibility on my actual problem. Thank you for your help :)